# Absurde Demonstration strategy

Tags: proof-verification

confused about the demonstration of the following statement :
let a, b, c $\in R^{*+}$ .

> Demonstrate that: $a*b\geq1$  OR   $a+b \leq \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$
>
> Demonstrate that ($a*b\geq1$  And   $a+b \leq \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$) 
>   if and only if $a*b=1$
>
> Let's suppose  that  ($a*b*c\geq1$  And   $a+b+c \leq \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$) , demonstrate that none of a,b and c is equal to 1 and that one of them is less than 1.

Comment: What are you confused about?

Comment: @SAM.Am Can you elaborate on why you are confused? If you don't provide any details or share or own attempts, most people will feel they are doing your homework for you...

Comment: The first two propositions seem straightforward enough, but the third proposition appears to be false; take $a=b=c=1$ as a counterexample. It's also strange to say "let $a,b,c\in\mathbb R^+$" and then prove that none of $a,b,c$ are real; moreover if none are real how can you say that one of them is less than $1.$ Is the last proposition correctly stated?

Comment: @PierreCarre  you are right, I tried to solve the second, which I posted underneath, but I am still  confused about the lack of information related to the first statement.

Comment: @DavidK I translated literally the third question from a French Exercise:
On suppose que  abc>=1 et  a+b+c >= 1/a +1/b +1/c ). Démontrer qu'aucun des Nombres  a,b,c  n'est égal à 1, et que l'un d'entre eux est inférieur à 1.

Comment: You seem to have statement c wrong.  First, the second inequality in  the comment is different from the one in the question.  Also, the comment says, "Show that none of them is equal to $1$," which is translated in the question as "none of them is real."

Comment: @saulspatz thanks for your comment, I update it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The question is still missing the “$+c$” from the comment, and I still don’t understand why $a=b=c=1$ isn’t a counterexample. My French is extremely poor, so I don’t know if there’s something else in the original that is still missing from the translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

second demonstration solution

> Demonstrate that ($a*b\geq1$  And   $a+b \leq \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$) 
>   if and only if $a*b=1$

$a*b\geq1$ => $a\geq \frac{1}{b}$ and $b\geq \frac{1}{a}$

so we have \begin{cases} a+b \geq \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}  \\a+b\leq \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}  \end{cases}

therefore $a+b = \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$
$=> a+b = \frac{a+b}{ab}$ so $ab = 1$

Comment: Also it’s not clear whether you considered the “if” direction of the proof, though that direction is easy.

Comment: @DavidK  you are right, it was a typo. I updated it. Thanks.  ( for the   "if". direction, do you mean I ought to start from that condition ?)

Comment: For the "if" I would start, "Given $ab = 1.$ Then ..." and you can pretty much write the result right away. Not a big thing, just a formality.

Comment: @DavidK. that was my humble translation from French language. (si et seulement si )